# Recover Notes from El Capitan in High Sierra

Tags: notes.app

My El Capitan machine unexpectedly died, and I salvaged the disk drive from it to put into an external enclosure attached to my new Mac, which runs High Sierra.  (I never used Sierra at all, since my old Mac couldn't support it.)

Now, how do I get the Notes from my El Capitan system into the High Sierra notes system?

(As I said, even though the old Mac threw-a-piston, I still have its drive, and therefore, all that notes-data.  But how do I *get* to it?)

Comment: On Notes >File> Import, then select the external drive here ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Notes/Data/Library/Notes/. Also if you use iCloud you have a copy of your Notes there.

Comment: As mentioned below, this doesn't work.  The files in that folder are grayed-out and can't be selected.  Interestingly, the "Import" button still goes through its paces even though nothing actually happens.

Answer (score 1):

Move old Notes (from your external drive) to iCloud

Drag and Drop

Allow it to sync (wait 5-10 minutes)

You should now see a duplicate Notes folders names (on your Mac (but not with exactly same content)

Those are the 2 Notes databases on iCloud

Now Select all Notes you want to keep and drag them over to new notes

Comment: It doesn't work.  When I navigate to the location you specified, I see filenames such as *NotesV7.storedata* but they are _grayed out_ and cannot be selected.  "Import" apparently declines to process this type of file.  (Oddly, when I click "import," it seems ready to do something even though no files were successfully selected!)  Nothing happens.

Comment: Other tasty-looking locations such as `com.apple.Notes.datastore` also do not seem to have any data-files in them!  (A subfolder named "Application Support/com.apple.Notes.datastore" is ... empty!)

Comment: @MikeRobinson You are right, it wont work, so let me delete this answer. Strangely Apple does not allow Notes to Import Notes ? Only if they are on iCloud.

Comment: @MikeRobinson OK, see my Updated answer, if it works for you, I did the process on my comouter

Answer (score 0):

Using the information supplied in answers and comments here, I was able to recover a lost note by searching my backup for all folders named "com.apple.Notes".  I quit Notes, unplugged the Internet, renamed all the "com.apple.Notes" folders, copied those from the backup into their parent folders, re-ran Notes, and my deleted notes reappeared! I then plugged the Internet back in, and the new Notes synced from iCloud without re-deleting the lost note.  Thanks to everyone who contributed here.